# Glade 3.X Non-Resizable Window

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I have been trying to get my main window created using Glade to show up as a default size of 1000 x 500 and not resizeable by the user.

Here are the settings I have used along with the window that shows up when I run my python script to build the window from the XML file:

[image]

If I check the 'Resizeable' box, the window shows up the proper size, but is then resizeable by the user. How can I get my main window to be the proper initial size, but not resizeable by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out. The default width/height don't seem to have any noticeable effect on the window that gets generated. I ended up having to go under the common tab and use the 'width request' and 'height request' options while also unchecking the resizeable option under the general tab.

[image]

[image]

The window then comes up at the desired size and is not resizeable.

I still don't get what default width/height do, but I can post back if I find out.